# Odd/Even selector with class in jquery

Tags: jquery

I have some jquery functions being run by clicking an `<a>` link deep inside the parent `<div>`'s UI have outlined below. I need to make sure the right function is applied as per the `<div>` in which it is nested when its clicked.

So, I have 3 functions to call on

$(".nectar-post-grid-item.single:nth-of-type(odd) a.link").click(function(){ ... });
This would mean all a.link buttons with the class "single" that are an odd number in the DOM use this click function
$(".nectar-post-grid-item.single:nth-of-type(even) a.link").click(function(){ ... });
This would mean all a.link buttons with the class "single" that are an even number in the DOM use this click function
$(".nectar-post-grid-item.double a.link").click(function(){ ... });
This would mean all a.link buttons with the class "double" in the DOM use this click function

The markup below changes on load as its random - but I need to make sure the 3 click functions I have above is applied to the correct divs based on their ordering as they appear in the DOM

If the divs appear as below all is fine and it works...

```
<div class="single nectar-post-grid-item"></div>
<div class="single nectar-post-grid-item"></div>
<div class="double nectar-post-grid-item"></div>
<div class="single nectar-post-grid-item"></div>
```

If a div with the class "double" comes in first, it messes things up and the odd / even I am using on the "single" targeted functions goes wrong and behaves incorrectly...

```
<div class="double nectar-post-grid-item"></div>
<div class="single nectar-post-grid-item"></div>
<div class="single nectar-post-grid-item"></div>
<div class="single nectar-post-grid-item"></div>
```

Is there a better way for me to write the targeting logic on the button click function?

I was hoping the odd/even would ignore the divs with "double" class - it seems it doesnt - can I adapt this code to ignore the double class?

SO, yeh, basically I want a way to target the odd divs with single applied for one click function, the even divs with single applied for another and the divs with double applied for a third. How can I get the selector to ignore the double divs and apply the correct function to the odd and even single divs?

Answer (score 1):

The CSS pseudo-classes `child` and `of-type` is of no use in your situation. They are blind to selectors in that they do not separate them from other classes, ids, etc. `child` is only concerned with a tag's position amonst it's siblings. `of-type` is a little more specific in that it will concern itself with a tag's `tagName` (ex. `a`, `div`, `section`, `input`, etc.). Also, the link within each div is meaningless in your situation because they are content of your target divs so clicking the div is the same as clicking the link unless the function invoked will behave differently somehow (very unlikely).

Use jQuery selectors `:even` and `:odd`, they will separate by index so use `:even` to get odd and vice versa.

```js
$('.A:even').on('click', evenA);
$('.A:odd').on('click', oddA);
$('.B:even').on('click', evenB);
$('.B:odd').on('click', oddB);

function evenA(e) {
  $(this).append(' ODD-A');
};

function oddA(e) {
  $(this).append(' EVEN-A');
};

function evenB(e) {
  $(this).append(' ODD-B');
};

function oddB(e) {
  $(this).append(' EVEN-B');
};
```

```html
<div class='A'>A1</div>
<div class='A'>A2</div>
<div class='B'>B1</div>
<div class='A'>A3</div>
<div class='B'>B2</div>
<div class='B'>B3</div>
<div class='A'>A4</div>
<div class='B'>B4</div>
<div class='A'>A5</div>
<div class='A'>A6</div>
<div class='A'>A7</div>
<div class='B'>B5</div>
<div class='A'>A8</div>
<div class='B'>B6</div>
<div class='B'>B7</div>
<div class='B'>B8</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help - it was the moving of divs in visual appearance on screen vs their sequence in the DOM that was messing up my logic - i've since resolved this by checking the left position of items on screen and reacting to that rather than the nth-of-type as css grid was moving some items from their DOM sequence to appear visually sequenced differently.

Comment: Yes, the true order of the HTML is always the HTML markup. If you get more divs dynamically my solution won't fail. I don't understand what you mean by checking left position but if it works for you, cool.

Answer (score 0):

I really think you were close. I'm left to presume that when you formed your links, you didn't add a class="link". You'll see why with my code below when I took the liberty of adding the links within the divs.

HTML

```
<div class="double nectar-post-grid-item"><a href="#">Item 1</a></div>
<div class="single nectar-post-grid-item"><a href="#">Item 2</a></div>
<div class="single nectar-post-grid-item"><a href="#">Item 3</a></div>
<div class="single nectar-post-grid-item"><a href="#">Item 4</a></div>
```

jQuery

```
$( ".nectar-post-grid-item.single:nth-of-type(odd) a" ).click( function() {
    console.log("I'm odd and single. Maybe I should do something about that.");
})

$( ".nectar-post-grid-item.single:nth-of-type(even) a" ).click( function() {
    console.log("I'm even and single. Does that make me Even Stephen?");
})

$( ".nectar-post-grid-item.double a" ).click( function() {
    console.log("I'm a double. I'm finally special.");
})
```

All I really did was remove the **.link** from your first two functions, then made a third function that was specific to the double class.

Using the example HTML that you said was problematic, if you click the first link, you'll get the double function. The other two work as expected if the order is even or odd.

Comment: Thanks - will this approach work if the order of the divs changes in the DOM and a double appears say at position 5? and not mess things up so that single div number 6 will then end of working with the odd link due to it appearing as item 7?

Comment: Thanks for your help - it was the moving of divs in visual appearance on screen vs their sequence in the DOM that was messing up my logic - i've since resolved this by checking the left position of items on screen and reacting to that rather than the nth-of-type as css grid was moving some items from their DOM sequence to appear visually sequenced differently.

Comment: Sounds like you have a solution. To answer your first question, the order of the divs does not affect the function triggers. I tested with 10 divs and randomly spread "single" and "double" classes. It still worked as expected.